# Select the first array only

Tags: php, arrays, api

I have a set of PHP arrays coming from an outside service. I only want the most recent however, how can I get this in PHP.

The Array is like this:

```
{"responseCode": 200, "message": "success"}
```

I am splitting it apart like this:

```
foreach ($submissions as $submissions) {
      print "<p><b>" . $submissions["message"] . "</b><br>";
    }
```

The problem is every time I do this, it returns the Message and Response Code from all of the arrays returned by my code. This is obviously due to the fact I am loping it, "for each" but how can I set this to only loop once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "<p><b>" . $submissions[0]["message"] . "</b><br>";
```

without the foreach...

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a loop if you're just trying to print the response code and message for the ***given*** JSON string:

```
$array = json_decode('{"responseCode": 200, "message": "success"}', true);
$resp_code = $array['responseCode'];
$message = $array['message'];
```

> The problem is every time I do this, it returns the Message and Response Code from all of the arrays returned by my code.

However, if your `JSON` string contains more instances of the same response code and message and you only need the ***first*** one, you can simply use a [`break`](http://php.net/break) statement.

Your `foreach` syntax looks rather incorrect, and it should be something like:

```
foreach($array as $value) {

    //echo the values

    break; //end execution
}
```

Learn more about [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop here.

Answer (score 0):

why you need to loop, when you need a particular value only.

```
print "<p><b>" . $submissions[0]["message"] . "</b><br>";
```

you can easily do it like above